# Understanding what happens when I add a new axis to a 3D Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unet-neural-network

I'm newbie with Python and Numpy Array.

I have 48 grey images of 240x240 on a Numpy Array with shape `(48, 240, 240)`.

If I print it, `print(my_array)`; I get this:

> ```
> [[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   ...
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
>
>  [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   ...
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
>
>  [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   ...
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
>
>  ...
>
>  [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   ...
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
>
>  [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   ...
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
>
>  [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   ...
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
>   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]]
> ```

Now, if I add a new axis, to use those images into a U-Net network, with the following code:
a = my_array[..., np.newaxis]

The shape for `a` is `(48, 240, 240, 1)`.

If I print it with `print(a)`:

> ```
> [[[[0.]
>    [0.]
>    [0.]
>    ...
>    [0.]
>    [0.]
>    [0.]]
>    ...
>   [[0.]
>    [0.]
>    [0.]
>    ...
>    [0.]
>    [0.]
>    [0.]]]]
> ```

Why the array has changed a lot?

Now, each element in `my_array` is a new array. I wondering if this will influence how the neural network works.

Comment: _Why the array has changed a lot?_ Did you not just add a new axis? What's the shape of the array after the change?

Comment: @AMC The shape for `a` is (48, 240, 240, 1).

Comment: So now the last dimension (which is displayed as columns) is size 1, that's the `[0.]` elements.  Add a dimension always changes the display.  The change is less obvious when the new dimension is first, more so when last.  But the change to the array itself is rather minor - just a change in shape (and strides).  The new array is a `view`, using the same underlying data buffer as the original.